How to submit a form and display the content from database to the Placeholder component in filament
I have a form, when i submit the form, it dispatches an event, which sends an external api request and then stores the response in the database. I have created an endpoint that can be used to check if the response has been stored in the database. I would like to use the Placeholder component to poll this endpoint, and display the content, without page refresh. See the image bellow. 
I am new to Filament, what is the possible solution to this?
